# Is it possible to use the Photoshop CS raw editor for JPG files?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, jpeg

I would like to use the editor that opens in PS CS5 when you open a Raw file.

I would like to use it on a jpeg file as I find it extremely useful to get the right colouring.

Is it possible?

Comment: There is a big difference internally in a JPG compared to a RAW file that seriously limits the range of changes you can do to the JPG image. Changing a JPG to RAW will not help much as the damage was done when saved as JPG, so avoid going to extremes.

Comment: @Greg, I agree this is not a replacement for shooting raw in the first place but it's a useful way to edit pictures from devices that don't support raw, such as camera phones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I use it a lot.

Open the settings for Camera Raw:

```
Edit > Preferences > Camera Raw
```

In the *JPEG and TIFF Handling* section at the bottom you can change the setting for JPEG to "Automatically open all supported JPEGs". Now when you open a JPEG file, it will open in Camera Raw.

Comment: Where is the setting for Camera Raw?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're referring to Adobe Camera Raw. If so you can use this same interface for JPEGs but you have to use a round about method to do it.

The only way I've found to open JPEGs in ACR is to use Adobe Bridge, right click on a JPEG and select "Open in Camera Raw...":

[image]

The white balance controls will behave slightly differently (you specify relative rather than absolute values) but I still find it a very useful way to edit JPEGs if you're used to processing raws.